# Null pointer Exception after logging out from a page having Applet

Tags: java, applet

We have an application where the user sees a login page and after login he gets redirected to a page having applet. The whole application runs in an applet. The applet is having swing components. Now the problem is when the user logs out of the application, intermittently he sees an exception on the login page. The exception comes as

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.clobber(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.removeCacheEntryImpl(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.access$100(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache$4.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.removeCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.removeCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.removeAllCacheEntries(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.CacheUtil.removeEntries(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.CacheUtil.remove(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.CacheUtil.remove(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.CacheUtil.remove(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.uninstallAll(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.uninstall(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.uninstallCache(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This comes in java popup as [image]

-----------------------------------------The code part----------------------------------

While the applet loads I am making a batch file with the command

`START /B javaws -uninstall`

This batch file gets called in a separate process when the applet's destroy method is called

```
@Override
    public void destroy() {

        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            @Override
            public Object run() {

String OSType = System.getProperty("os.name");
                if ( OSType.contains("Windows") || OSType.contains("windows")){
                    final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(batchFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                    builder.directory(batchFile.getParentFile());
                    try {
                        builder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                   
                }else{
                    if(shellFile.exists()){
                        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellFile.getAbsolutePath()+" &");
                        //in case if any error occurs , lets print the error stream
                        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                        String line = stdError.readLine();
                        while(line != null){
                            System.out.println(line);
                            line = stdError.readLine();
                        }                           
                    }
                }
}
}
```

Comment: Won't be able to help you without any code.

Comment: Can u provide the code...

Comment: Can you create a scenario to repeat this error?

Comment: I have added the code now.

Comment: Please check the windows code. This problem is occuring in Windows. However no one has tested linux as well.

Comment: please add more error log so we can see where in your code it happens. After that we can come up with a possible cause

Comment: Basically I am trying to delete the java cache after the user logs out of the application. So I have created a batch file. And this batch file gets called in a separate process from the destroy method of applet. This is the only log I have, No other log is getting generated.